# How to delete a file to the trash in BASH (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, rm, trash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make `rm` move to trash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42757/make-rm-move-to-trash)

I've looked everywhere for the answer, but I can't find it.

Is it possible to move/delete a file to the trash folder on linux. But also having the trashinfo file.

E.g I can move the file into the trash folder fine, but I don't have the trashinfo file.

tldr; How to delete a file to trash in BASH

Also, I'm using Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 4):

I'll copy [my SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13532284/341459) here:

In Ubuntu the trash files are kept in `~/.local/share/Trash/files`

There is a [trash command line interface](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli) that you can use. To install do:

```
sudo apt-get install trash-cli
```

Then, to trash something do:

```
trash-put myfile.txt
```