# Why was `cp` designed to silently overwrite existing files?

Tags: cp, history

I tested `cp` with the following commands:

```
$ ls
first.html   second.html  third.html

$ cat first.html
first

$ cat second.html
second

$ cat third.html
third
```

Then I copy `first.html` to `second.html`:

```
$ cp first.html second.html

$ cat second.html
first
```

The file `second.html` is silently overwritten without any errors. However, if I do it in a desktop GUI by dragging and dropping a file with the same name, it will be suffixed as `first1.html` automatically. This avoids accidentally overwriting an existing file.

Why doesn't `cp` follow this pattern instead of overwriting files silently?

Comment: I imagine only the coreutils designers can truly answer the question, but it's just the way it works for now. Usually the apps are built assuming the user really means what they're doing and to minimize the extra prompting.

If you want to change the behavior, alias 'cp' to 'cp -i' or 'cp -n'.

Comment: @kevlinux The coreutils devs are just implementing the POSIX standard.

Comment: @Kusalananda Right, so the question is, why does the POSIX standard mandate this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You would have to talk to someone on the standard's committee about that as it's not revealed in the Rationale.

Comment: Because back when it was designed people wanted to be as terse as possible with what they do (hence cp not copy) and knew what they did and when they made mistakes they did not try to blame tools. It was a totally different kind of people back then that did computers. Its like asking why a scalpel for a heart surgeon can cut into hands too.

Comment: This might have also been asked on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: imagine having `cp foo bar && some-command --input-file bar`. This would be using an older `bar` if the `cp` created instead a `bar (copy)` file. Of course I could add `rm foo` at the beginning, but that shouldn't be necessary, and by having `cp` overwrite the destination file it isn't.

Comment: Related: [The UNIX-HATERS Handbook](http://web.mit.edu/~simsong/www/ugh.pdf) See "Accidents Will Happen"

Comment: Early UNIX philosophy tended to assume that only highly trained professionals would use computers *at all*, ever. Therefore efficiency of operation was prioritized over protecting users from themselves. If you say "copy A to B", then you definitely want to have the content of A available in B; you *might* have forgotten that B already has valuable content, but that's not worth complicating the more likely case for.

Comment: Unix was designed by and for computer-experts, with the assumption that the user knew what he was doing.  The OS would do exactly what the user told it to if possible - without holding the user's hand and without asking for endless confirmations.  If an operation overwrote something, it was assumed that was what the user wanted.  Also remember that this was the early 1970s - pre-MS DOS, Windows and home computers - guiding and holding the user's hand every step of the way, was not yet common.  Also, with teletype-machined as terminals, asking for confirmations always would be too cumbersome.

Comment: Don't alias `cp` to `cp -i` or similar because you'll get used to having a safety net, making systems where it's not available (most of them) that much more risky. Better to teach yourself to routinely `cp -i` etc. if that's what you prefer.

Comment: @kevlinux What do you mean by "apps"? `cp` is not an "app", whatever those things are. It's a Unix tool: Unix never says PLEASE; it also never says SORRY. It does what you tell it to do. If you tell it to do dumb things, then the fault my dear Horatio lies not with your Unix `*`s but with your own faulty orders.  :)  We don't need Clippy to popup a window saying "Are you really, really sure?" every time we want to increment a machine register.

Comment: Whatever the historical reason, IMO this behaviour is exactly right especially today. Every slightly important file should be under version control and have at least two backups. If you accidentally delete a file twice a year, costs you two `git checkout -p` commands. About a minute per year. If I had to confirm every file I _wanted_ to be overwritten by `cp`, it would take me about five minutes every _week_. (Not for the confirmation itself, but for figuring out why it happens and how I should pre-remove those files in the future.)

Comment: @tchrist A software application "app" not an "app" like everything else is now. Call it a tool, utility, program, whatever, it's still a software application.

Comment: @kevlinux Do you mean it’s a program?

Comment: Given that you know that the default behaviour of `cp` is to overwrite its target (if it's a file), what is your issue with this? Given that your GUI thingy works differently, why is your issue not with that tool instead? If this question, instead of asking "why?", asked "how?" (i.e. "how may I make `cp` do what my GUI tool does?"), it would be easier to answer in an opinion-neutral way.

Comment: This idea that the authors of cp were were from a world of flawless men that never made any error when using commands, or whatever other justification, should address why in the case of mv , mv won't overwrite a directory that already exists.

Comment: Note: `cp -al` is not designed to silently overwrite, though.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[The default overwrite behavior of `cp` is specified in POSIX.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html)

> 3. If source_file is of type regular file, the following steps shall be taken:
>
>    3.a. The behavior is unspecified if dest_file exists and was written by a previous step. Otherwise, if dest_file exists, the following steps shall be taken:
>
>    3.a.i. If the -i option is in effect, the cp utility shall write a prompt to the standard error and read a line from the standard input. If the response is not affirmative, cp shall do nothing more with source_file and go on to any remaining files.
>
>    3.a.ii. A file descriptor for dest_file shall be obtained by performing actions equivalent to the open() function defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2017 called using dest_file as the path argument, and the bitwise-inclusive OR of O_WRONLY and O_TRUNC as the oflag argument.
>
>    3.a.iii. If the attempt to obtain a file descriptor fails and the -f option is in effect, cp shall attempt to remove the file by performing actions equivalent to the unlink() function defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2017 called using dest_file as the path argument. If this attempt succeeds, cp shall continue with step 3b.

When the POSIX specification was written, there already was a large number of scripts in existence, with a built-in assumption for the default overwrite behavior. Many of those scripts were designed to run without direct user presence, e.g. as cron jobs or other background tasks. Changing the behavior would have broken them. Reviewing and modifying them all to add an option to force overwriting wherever needed was probably considered a huge task with minimal benefits.

Also, the Unix command line was always designed to allow an experienced user to work efficiently, even at the expense of a hard learning curve for a beginner. When the user enters a command, the computer is to expect that the user really means it, without any second-guessing; it is the user's responsibility to be careful with potentially destructive commands.

When the original Unix was developed, the systems then had so little memory and mass storage compared to modern computers that overwrite warnings and prompts were probably seen as wasteful and unnecessary luxuries.

When the POSIX standard was being written, the precedent was firmly established, and the writers of the standard were well aware of the virtues of **not breaking backwards compatibility**.

Besides, as others have described, any user can add/enable those features for themselves, by using shell aliases or even by building a replacement `cp` command and modifying their `$PATH` to find the replacement before the standard system command, and get the safety net that way if desired.

But if you do so, you'll find that you are creating a hazard for yourself. If the `cp` command behaves one way when used interactively and another way when called from a script, you may not remember that the difference exists. On another system, you might end up being careless because you're become used to the warnings and prompts on your own system.

If the behavior in scripts will still match the POSIX standard, you're likely to get used to the prompts in interactive use, then write a script that does some mass copying - and then find you're again inadvertently overwritten something.

If you enforce prompting in scripts too, what will the command do when run in a context that has no user around, e.g. background processes or cron jobs? Will the script hang, abort, or overwrite?

Hanging or aborting means that a task that was supposed to get done automatically will not be done. Not overwriting may sometimes also cause a problem by itself: for example, it might cause old data to be processed twice by another system instead of being replaced with up-to-date data.

A large part of the power of the command line comes from the fact that **once you know how to do something on the command line, you'll implicitly also know how to make it happen automatically by scripting**. But that is only true if the commands you use interactively also work exactly the same when invoked in a script context. Any significant differences in behavior between interactive use and scripted use will create a sort of cognitive dissonance which is annoying to a power user.

Comment: "Why does it work like this?" "Because the standard says so." "Why does the standard say so?" "Because it already worked liked this."

Comment: The last paragraph is the real reason. Confirmation dialogs and "_Do you really want to do this?_" prompts are for wimps :-)

Comment: @BaptisteCandellier - Agreed. Its like the ultimate reason is out there, but tantalizingly just out of this answer's reach.

Comment: Tip: if you are still learning start every command with `echo ` so that if you accidentally press enter all it does is printing the command line and thus you can review it. When you are sure you want to run the command `echo` printed simply do `^echo ^^` and the last cmdline will execute without the `echo ` part.
Alternatively: write to a file to your heart content and copy&paste when you are sure.

Comment: That last paragraph is why `rm -rf` is so effective, even if you didn't actually mean to run it in your home directory...

Comment: @T.E.D. Funny how nobody ever mentions how [the unlink(2) syscall](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=unlink&sektion=2) also ‘fails’ to ask *“Mother, may I?”* for confirmation whenever these sempiternal discussions again rear their dainty heads. :)

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Comment: Interesting point about hanging. I.e. if you run `cp` as a background job (`&`), then it can't read from the terminal. On modern UNIX, `touch a b; cp -i a b &` will say `cp: overwrite 'b'? `, but `cp` will be stopped (and you get a message about that as well).  You can put `cp` back in the foreground (`fg`), but it does not re-print `cp: overwrite 'b'? `.  Problem: in more complex scenarios, you can lose track of what it was asking. I'm not sure how useful prompting is for `cp` though. Maybe it's more useful to just have `cp` that treats overwrite as a mistake, and `cp -f` that does overwrite.

Answer (score 24):

`cp` comes from the beginning of Unix. It was there well before the Posix standard was written. Indeed: Posix just formalized the existing behavior of `cp` in this regard.

We're talking around Epoch (1970-01-01), when men were real men, women were real women and furry little creatures ... (I digress). In those days, adding extra code made a program bigger. That was an issue then, because the first computer that ran Unix was a PDP-7 (upgradable to 144KB RAM!). So things were small, efficient, without safety-features.

So, in those days, you had to know what you were doing, because the computer just did not have the power to prevent you from doing anything you regretted later.

(There is a nice cartoon by Zevar; search for "zevar cerveaux assiste par ordinateur" to find the evolution of the computer. Or try http://a54.idata.over-blog.com/2/07/74/62/dessins-et-bd/le-CAO-de-Zevar---reduc.jpg for as long as it exists)

For those really interested (I saw some speculation in the comments): The original `cp` on the first Unix was about two pages of assembler code (C came later). The relevant part was:

```
sys open; name1: 0; 0   " Open the input file
spa
  jmp error         " File open error
lac o17         " Why load 15 (017) into AC?
sys creat; name2: 0     " Create the output file
spa
  jmp error         " File create error
```

(So, a hard `sys creat`)

And, while we're at it: Version 2 of Unix used (code sniplet)

```
mode = buf[2] & 037;
if((fnew = creat(argv[2],mode)) < 0){
    stat(argv[2], buf);
```

which is also a hard `creat` without tests or safeguards. Note that the C-code for V2 Unix of `cp` is less than 55 lines!

Comment: Almost correct, excepr it's "_small furry_" (creatures from Alpha Centauri) not "_furry little_"!

Comment: @T.E.D.: It's entirely possible early versions of `cp` just `open`ed the destination with `O_CREAT | O_TRUNC` and performed a `read`/`write` loop; sure, with modern `cp` there are so many knobs that it basically has to try to `stat` the destination beforehand, and could easily check for existence first (and does with `cp -i`/`cp -n`), but if the expectations were established from original, bare bones `cp` tools, changing that behavior would break existing scripts needlessly. It's not like modern shells with `alias` can't just make `cp -i` the default for interactive use after all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - Hmmm. You're quite right that I really have no idea if it was easy or hard to do. Comment deleted.

Comment: Huh what. The only match for your search for is this answer.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah, but then that's just pushing the hard lesson down the road until it's on a production system...

Comment: @ShadowRanger @T.E.D. I found that `cp` pre-dates `O_CREAT` and `O_TRUNC` (and `O_EXCL`, which can be used to easily fail on existing files :-).  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477401/why-was-cp-designed-to-silently-overwrite-existing-files?noredirect=1#comment873195_477600  The man pages for the system calls in UNIX V6 are available e.g. here: https://minnie.tuhs.org//cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/man/man2/

Comment: @sourcejedi: Fun! Doesn't change my basic theory (that it was easier to just unconditionally open with truncation, and `creat` happens to be equivalent to `open`+`O_CREAT | O_TRUNC`), but the lack of `O_EXCL` does explain why it wouldn't have been so easy to handle existing files; trying to do so would be inherently racy (you'd basically have to `open`/`stat` to check existence, then use `creat`, but on large shared systems, it's always possible by the time you got to `creat`, someone else made the file and now you've blown it away anyway). May as well just overwrite unconditionally.

Answer (score 19):

Because these commands are also meant to be used in scripts, possibly running without any kind of human supervision, and also because there are plenty of cases where you indeed want to overwrite the target (the philosophy of the Linux shells is that the human knows what s/he is doing)

There are still a few safeguards:

- GNU `cp` has a `-n`|`--no-clobber` option
- if you copy several files to a single one `cp` will complain that the last one is not a directory.

Comment: This only applies to a vendor specific implementation and the question was not about that vendor specific implementation.

Answer (score 11):

> Is it "do one thing at one time"?

This comment sounds like a question about a general design principle.  Often, questions about these are very subjective, and we are not able to write a proper answer.  Be warned that we may close questions in this case.

Sometimes we have an explanation for the original design choice, because the developer(s) have written about them.  But I don't have such a nice answer for this question.

### Why `cp` is designed this way?

The problem is Unix is over 40 years old.

If you were creating a new system now, you might make different design choices.  But changing Unix would break existing scripts, as mentioned in other answers.

### Why *was* `cp` designed to silently overwrite existing files?

The short answer is "I don't know" :-).

Understand that `cp` is only one problem.  I think none of the original command programs protected against overwriting or deleting files.  The shell has a similar problem when redirecting output:

```
$ cat first.html > second.html
```

This command also silently overwrites `second.html`.

I am interested to think how all these programs could be redesigned.  It might require some extra complexity.

**I think this is part of the explanation: early Unix emphasized simple *implementations*.** For a more detailed explanation of this, see "worse is better", linked at the end of this answer.

You could change `> second.html` so it stops with an error, if `second.html` already exists.  However as we mentioned, sometimes the user *does* want to replace an existing file.  For example, she may be building up a complex command, trying several times until it does what she wants.

The user could run `rm second.html` first if she needs to.  This might be a good compromise!  It has some possible disadvantages of its own.

1. The user must type the filename twice.
2. People also get in to a lot of trouble using `rm`.  So I would like to make `rm` safer as well.  But how?  If we make `rm` show each filename and ask the user to confirm, she now has to write *three* lines of commands instead of one.  Also, if she has to do this too often, she will get into a habit and type "y" to confirm without thinking.  So it could be very annoying, and it could *still* be dangerous.

On a modern system, I recommend [installing the `trash` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184787/29483), and using it instead of `rm` where possible.  The introduction of Trash storage was a great idea e.g. [for a single-user graphical PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Mac_OS).

I think it is also important to understand the limitations of the original Unix hardware - limited RAM and disk space, output displayed on slow [printers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter#Teleprinters_in_computing)  as well as the system and development software.

Notice that original Unix did not have [tab completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_completion), to quickly fill in a filename for an `rm` command.  (Also, the original Bourne shell does not have command history, e.g. like when you use the Up arrow key in `bash`).

With printer output, you would use line-based editor, `ed`.  This is harder to learn than a visual text editor.  You have to print some current lines, decide how you want to change them, and type an edit command.

Using `> second.html` is a bit like using a command in a line-editor.  The effect it has depends on the current state.  (If `second.html` already exists, its content will be discarded).  If the user is not sure about the current state, she is expected to run `ls` or `ls second.html` first.

### "Simple implementation" as a design principle

There is a popular interpretation of Unix design, which begins:

> The design must be simple, both in implementation and interface. It is more important for the implementation to be simple than the interface. Simplicity is the most important consideration in a design.
>
> ...
>
> Gabriel argued that "Worse is better" produced more successful software than the MIT approach: As long as the initial program is basically good, it will take much less time and effort to implement initially and it will be easier to adapt to new situations. Porting software to new machines, for example, becomes far easier this way. Thus its use will spread rapidly, long before a [better] program has a chance to be developed and deployed (first-mover advantage).
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worse_is_better

Comment: Why is overwriting the target with `cp` a "problem"? Having it interactively ask for permission, or fail may be as big a "problem" as that.

Comment: wow, thank you. complement the guideline: 1) Write programs that do one thing and do it well.
2) Trust the programmer.

Comment: @Kusalananda data loss is a problem. I personally am interested in reducing the risk that I lose data. There are various approaches to this. Saying that it is a problem does not mean the alternatives do not also have problems.

Comment: @Kusalananda I am more interested in trying to keep my answer simple to read - which is something I struggle with! - than not offending people who love Unix :-).  I particularly do not want to add too many qualifiers, or use too many different words at once, when the English in the question is not perfect :-).

Comment: @sourcejedi No worries. The word "issue" may be less contentious than "problem".

Comment: @riderdragon I edited my answer to put my opinion in bold text. "Trust the programmer" is a good description. It was probably an important reason for this design. I did not like to write it: I would also want to write that "trust the programmer" can be bad.

Comment: @riderdragon Programs written in the C language can often fail in very surprising ways, because C trusts the programmer. But programmers are just not that reliable. We have to write very advanced tools, like  [valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind), which are needed to try and find the mistakes that programmers make. I think it is important to have programming languages like Rust or Python or C# that try to enforce "memory safety" without trusting the programmer.  (The C language was created by one of the authors of UNIX, in order to write UNIX in a portable language).

Comment: Even better is `cat first.html second.html > first.html` will give result in `first.html` being overwritten with the contents of `second.html` only. The original contents are lost for all time.

Comment: What do you mean we can't get a proper answer? Just ask [Ken](https://dblp.org/pers/hd/t/Thompson:Ken), he knows everything.

Answer (score 11):

The design of "cp" goes back to the original design of Unix. There in fact was a coherent philosophy behind the Unix design, which has been slightly less that half-jokingly been referred to as [Worse-is-Better](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worse_is_better)<sup>*</sup>.

The basic idea is that keeping the code simple is actually a more important design consideration that having a perfect interface or "doing The Right Thing".

> - Simplicity -- the design must be simple, both in implementation and
>     interface. *It is more important for the implementation to be simple
>     than the interface*. Simplicity is the most important consideration in
>     a design.
> - Correctness -- the design must be correct in all
>     observable aspects. It is slightly better to be simple than correct.
> - Consistency -- the design must not be overly inconsistent.
>     Consistency can be sacrificed for simplicity in some cases, but *it is
>     better to drop those parts of the design that deal with less common
>     circumstances* than to introduce either implementational complexity or
>     inconsistency.
> - Completeness -- the design must cover as many
>     important situations as is practical. All reasonably expected cases
>     should be covered. Completeness can be sacrificed in favor of any
>     other quality. In fact, completeness must be sacrificed whenever
>     implementation simplicity is jeopardized. Consistency can be
>     sacrificed to achieve completeness if simplicity is retained;
>     especially worthless is consistency of interface.

<sup>(*emphasis mine*)</sup>

Remembering that this was 1970, the use case of "I want to copy this file *only* if it doesn't already exist" would have been a fairly rare use case for someone performing a copy. If that's what you wanted, you'd be quite capable of checking before the copy, and that can even be scripted.

As to why an OS with that design approach happened to be the one that won out over all other OS's being built at the time, the author of the essay had a theory for that as well.

> A further benefit of the worse-is-better philosophy is that the
>   programmer is conditioned to sacrifice some safety, convenience, and
>   hassle to get good performance and modest resource use. Programs
>   written using the New Jersey approach will work well both in small
>   machines and large ones, and the code will be portable because it is
>   written on top of a virus.
>
> It is important to remember that the initial virus has to be basically
>   good. If so, the viral spread is assured as long as it is portable.
>   Once the virus has spread, there will be pressure to improve it,
>   possibly by increasing its functionality closer to 90%, but users have
>   already been conditioned to accept worse than the right thing.
>   Therefore, the worse-is-better software first will gain acceptance,
>   second will condition its users to expect less, and third will be
>   improved to a point that is almost the right thing.

<sup>* - or what the author, but nobody else, called "The New Jersey approach"</sup>.

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: +1, but I think it would help to have a concrete example. When you install a new version of a program that you've edited and re-compiled (and maybe tested :-), you deliberately want to overwrite the old version of the program. (And you probably want similar behaviour from your compiler. So early UNIX only has `creat()` v.s. `open()`. `open()` could not create a file if it did not exist.  It only takes 0/1/2 for read/write/both. It does not yet take `O_CREAT`, and there is no `O_EXCL`).

Comment: @sourcejedi - Sorry, but as a software developer myself, I honestly can't think of another scenario than that one where I'd be doing a copy. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D. sorry, I mean I'm suggesting this example, as one of the non-rare cases where you definitely want an overwrite, v.s. the comparison in the question where maybe you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that **a GUI is by definition interactive,** while a binary like `/bin/cp` is just a program which can be called from all kinds of places, for example from your GUI ;-). I'd bet that even today the vast majority of calls to `/bin/cp` will not be from a real terminal with a user typing a shell command but rather from a HTTP server or a mail system or a NAS. **A built-in protection against user errors makes complete sense in an interactive environment;** less so in a simple binary. For example, your GUI will most likely call `/bin/cp` in the background to perform the actual operations and would have to deal with the safety questions on standard out even though it just asked the user!

Note that it was from day one close to trivial to write a safe wrapper around `/bin/cp` if so desired. The *nix philosophy is to provide simple building blocks for users: of these, `/bin/cp` is one.