# Moving files to a bin

Tags: files, scripting, rm, inode

I am having issues with my code below:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#Removing Files into the Recycle Bin(Deleted Directory)
filemove=$1 #Saving the first argument as "filemove"
mkdir -p ~/deleted #Create the deleted directory if it doesn't exist
mv $filemove ~/deleted #Moves the file
```

I need the files in the recycle bin to follow a format as: `filename_inode`.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! Just to clarify your question, you're asking for "the next line of code" -- to do what? You've already moved the file.  Are you now trying to rename it to include the inode? Consider renaming during the `mv`?  Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/519271/edit) with any further clarifications. Thank you, and welcome to the site! Don't forget to [take our tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to become more familiar with the site.

Comment: You might better use some ready solutions: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/213533/command-to-move-a-file-to-trash-via-terminal or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42757/make-rm-move-to-trash

Comment: I am trying to put files the into the recycle bin after being removed. I need the files in the recycle bin to follow a format as: filename_inode.

Answer (score 4):

- Use `stat` tool to get inode number.
- rename directly using `mv`.
- Quote filenames (!!), e.g. `"$filemove"`, never `$filemove`.
- Add some checking for security before moving `[ ! -e "$target" ] && mv ...`
- Use `set -euo pipefail` at the beginning of the script, so it fails on any error.
- Use `for f in "$@"; do ... done` loop to allow multiple files as arguments.
- Again: Quote filenames (!!).
- You might be better off using some ready solutions, e.g. see:

  - [Command to move a file to Trash via Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213533/command-to-move-a-file-to-trash-via-terminal)
  - [Make `rm` move to trash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42757/make-rm-move-to-trash)

---

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Removing Files into the Recycle Bin (Deleted Directory)

set -euo pipefail #make script exit on any error

mkdir -p "$HOME/deleted"
dest="$HOME/deleted/${1}_$(stat --format %i "$1")"

# check if file exists, and if not, do the move!
[ -e "$dest" ] && echo "Target exists, not moving: $1" ||  mv "$1" "$dest"
```

Use like `trash file1` or  `trash "file with spaces"`

(assuming `trash` being the script name...)

---

or to be able to trash multiple files at once:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Removing Files into the Recycle Bin (Deleted Directory)

set -euo pipefail #make script exit on any error

mkdir -p "$HOME/deleted"

for f in "$@"; do
    dest="$HOME/deleted/${f}_$(stat --format %i "$f")"
    # check if file exists, and if not, do the move!
    [ -e "$dest" ] && echo "Target exists, skipped moving: $f" ||  mv "$f" "$dest"
done
```

Use like `trash file1 file2 "file with spaces"`

Comment: before you copy paste my script, make sure you understand every single bit of it. I did not test it!

Comment: I'm doing that now! I wasn't copying and pasting that's plagiarism just getting a idea of what I need to do. I really appreciate it

Comment: If you liked an answer, you might consider an upvote, and if it worked for you, accept it by clicking the check mark on the left ;-)

Comment: I have no issue with that :D thanks again I wish I can do more to recommend you but I am new to the site